# PHP array mapping

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping

Is there a cleaner way than `foreach` to get an array of all "label" values?

```
$methods[0]['label'] = 'test';
$methods[0]['nr']    = 99;
$methods[1]['label'] = 'whatever';
$methods[1]['nr']    = 10;


foreach($methods as $method) {
    $methodsLabel[] = $method['label'];
}
```

Comment: I do not think foreach is unclean. Do you think it is unclean because you prefer functional programming?

Comment: I also think your code is just fine the way it is. Not only will it be fast, but also very easy to read and maintain... everyone knows how to look at a foreach!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of PHP 5.5+, this is exactly what [**`array_column()`**](http://php.net/manual/function.array-column.php) does:

```
$methodsLabel = array_column($methods, 'label');
```

http://php.net/manual/function.array-column.php

---

3v4l example: https://3v4l.org/ZabAb

Comment: This is an interesting find as my Sublime Text doesn't know of that function and, therefore, doesn't provide auto completion for this.

Answer (score 29):

No, there is no faster way than your implemented code.  All other methods will be slower due to the overhead of a function call.  For a small array the difference will be trivial, but for a large one (100 members or so, depending on implementation), the difference can be huge...

You could `array_map` it, but I'd stick with the raw PHP you posted above...  It's easier to maintain and IMHO more readable...

After all, tell me which **at a glance** tells you what it does more:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $results[] = $value['title'];
}
```

vs

```
$results = array_map(function($element) {
        return $element['title'];
    },
    $array
);
```

Or:

```
$callback = function($element) {
    return $element['title'];
}
$results = array_map($callback, $array);
```

Personally, the first does it for me the best.  It's immediately obvious without knowing *anything* what it's doing.  The others require knowledge of `array_map` semantics to understand.  Couple that with the fact that `array_map` *is* slower, and it's a double win for `foreach`.

Code should only be as elegant as necessary.  It should be readable above all else...

Comment: I changed my description, I was not searching for a fast solution I was searching for a more cleaner solution.

Comment: @powtac: I still stand behind a straight foreach is more readable and easier to understand.  And you're talking the same if not less code with the foreach, so I fail to see the benefit...

Answer (score 18):

Sure, use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function getLabelFromMethod($method) {
   return $method['label'];
}

$labels = array_map('getLabelFromMethod', $methods);
```

If you are on PHP 5.3+, you can also use a lambda function:

```
$labels = array_map(function($m) {
   return $m['label'];
}, $methods);
```

Comment: Ok, but this are still 3 lines of code and also it requires to define an extra method. :( And for the moment I search for a nice solution in PHP < 5.3.

Comment: Beside array_map() there is no other solution?

Comment: I tried this for something similar and it was slow as hell.  Faster just to use the foreach directly.

Comment: The `foreach` seems "ugly" for me in this case.

Answer (score 6):

```
array_map('array_shift', $methods);
```

Here assumption is that label will be the first element of each array.

Comment: @Gaurav @ircmaxell Okay, that's really nice. +1

Comment: Be very careful with this.  If the assumption breaks for any reason (that the `label` is sorted differently for any reason), the code will return incorrect results.

Comment: @ircmaxell : Yes, need to be careful here.

Answer (score 5):

On PHP 5.3+ you can use an anonymous function paired with array_map.

```
$methodsLabel = array_map(function($item) { return $item['label']; }, $methods);
```

Comment: Didn't realize you needed pre-PHP5.3.

Comment: Added it later... ;) After I saw your solution.

Answer (score 3):

If label is first element in array then "current" with [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will work fine.

```
array_map('current', $methods);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Arrow functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions) have been introduced into PHP 7.4, which makes this a little bit cleaner.

```
$methodsLabel = array_map(fn($x) => $x['label'], $methods)
```